# Why didn't military attack the spaceship in the end?

Tags: movie, super-8

In the end of *Super 8* movie, when the spaceship started to form over water tank which was pulling all metallic objects from vicinity, why didn't military blow that up? That could be a weapon (most likely because the alien was hostile in nature).

Military also had orders for using heavy firepower. And, there was a tank near water tank too.

Comment: Maybe they knew they couldn't destroy the cubes? Surely they had studied them a lot

Comment: @SSumner Are you sure that the spaceship was formed by cubes?

Comment: Yes. You don't remember all the cubes forming together then molding into the spaceship on top of the tower?

Comment: @SSumner Weren't all cubes (minus few ones) under custody of military?

Comment: From [here](http://super8.wikia.com/wiki/Argus_Cubes) - `The Air Force tried to lure the alien with the cubes, but it over-powered them and used his ability to attract all the cubes to the top of the water tower and reconstituted his ship, which he used to finally escape planet Earth.`

Answer (score 4):

By that part of the film, as can be seen in the battle in the town, the military had lost control over their weapons systems. The alien was free to do as it pleased. And since the alien was utilizing the weapons and hardware close at hand as it prepared the spacecraft for its escape, it seems reasonable to assume attacking the creature and/or it's spaceship at that time was both impossible and pointless.